# Firefox cannot recognize certificates for well-known sites

Tags: firefox, certificate

When trying to connect to well-known sites, for instance `hotmail.com`, Firefox shows that

> This Connection in Untrusted

In *Options* → *Advanced* → *Certificates*, it's configured to select one matching certificate automatically. Why does Firefox not trust the current connection? Can it be a [man-in-the-middle attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack) (MITM) or it's something like broken certificate storage on my computer?

[image]

[image]

The *Technical Details* section of the Firefox error page shows:

> login.live.com uses an invalid security certificate.  The certificate is not trusted because no issuer chain was provided.  (Error code: sec_error_unknown_issuer)

---

Solved: the problem is Antivirus Web Access protection. It interferes with the HTTPS connection. Similar to a man-in-the-middle attack? Why can *[ESET Smart Security](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ESET#Recognition)* not do it correctly?

[image]

Comment: Could be either or something else. The details of the certificate in question would help in getting a more specific answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please check the **time and date** on your computer. An incorrect clock setting (for example, due to an empty BIOS battery) is the most popular cause of such problem. The SSL certificates are valid only in a defined date range (from/to). If your clock has been reset, certificates are "not yet valid" :D

Comment: ```login.live.com uses an invalid security certificate.

The certificate is not trusted because no issuer chain was provided.

(Error code: sec_error_unknown_issuer)```

Answer (score 1):

In order for *[ESET Smart Security](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ESET#Recognition)* to examine the data inside an HTTPS connection for malicious behavior, it *has* to MITM your connection. However, how this usually works is that they install their root certificate in your browser's list of trusted root certificates, so everything looks fine.

This has several security downfalls, however, including potentially making all of your private Internet browsing decryptable by *ESET Smart Security*. Likely the installer configured the root certificates for [Internet Explorer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer), but not Firefox, thus the errors. You can probably check their support site for how to configure their certificate properly if you want to analyze HTTPS traffic.